# How does sharepoint place users into the "browse" function for the people picker

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, people-picker

I have noticed that after a clean install of SharePoint 2010 Foundation the people picker's "browse" function search does not find any of the local users on the server that Foundation was installed on.

If I type in the exact username and click "Check Names" it is validated and a prefix like "MachineName\User1" is added.

Once a user has been added to the site they can then be searched via the "browse" button. If they have not been added, the "browse" button search will not reveal them.

Is this how SharePoint is supposed to work? Do I need to add all the local users to a generic location in the site in order for them to be searchable in the browse window? This is my first "official" installation of what will become a production site, so I haven't dealt with these account issues in the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much fuming and some research it appears that SharePoint only adds users from Active Directory into the "Browse" function from the "People and Groups" people picker. After converting my SharePoint machine into a Domain Controller all of the users that had been local became searchable as they were now a member of the domain.

Would be nice to be able to search local users if desired! The server is completely standalone and so it seems a bit unnecessary to turn it into a domain controller...